# Get async callback value in unittest debug

Tags: c#, delegates, callback

I got UnitTest method which calls method with callback

```
    [Test]
    public void GetUserAsyncTest()
    {
        User result;
        _restTest.GetUserAsync((user) =>
                                   {
                                       result = user;
                                   });

       Assert.AreEqual("xy", result.Email);
    }
```

This is my method signature

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve the User details for the currently authenticated User
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="callback">Method to call upon successful completion</param>
    public void GetUserAsync(Action<User> callback)
```

How can I test this and get value from callback? Currently my result is always null which is logical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an event to wait until the async method has finished:

```
[Test]
public void GetUserAsyncTest()
{
    //Action<User> user = null;
    User result;
    ManualResetEvent waitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    _restTest.GetUserAsync((user) =>
    {
        result = user;
        waitEvent.Set();
    });

    waitEvent.WaitOne();

    Assert.AreEqual("xy", result.Email);
}
```

Also changed `user.Email` to `result.Email`. Suspected you want to check the `result` variable.

Comment: Yes, it was my typing error for result, so I updated the code